# EF Core in memory, delete unit testing giving error: entity already tracked

Tags: entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

I am working with entity framework core in memory to test my code.I created in memory context and added data. I have delete method which is going to delete record with id=1. Test method is throwing error following error:

> The instance of entity type 'cats' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 204}' is already being tracked When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

Could any one help me , how to resolve this issue. I tried different scenarios on internet, but nothing did not work.

**Test.cs:**

```
   [Fact(DisplayName ="Delete Service Must Return Result")]
    public void DeleteService()
    {
        var serviceId = _collectionFixture.context.cat.Where(x => x.Id == 201).AsNoTracking();

       var okObject = _collectionFixture.CatController.DeleteService(serviceId) as OkObjectResult;

          var baseResponse = okObject.Value as BaseResponse;
           Assert.True(baseResponse.Success);
    }
```

my service class:

public catResponse DeleteService(int serviceId)
          {
               try{

```
               var serviceDto = _Context.catserviceTreatment.Where(x => x.Id 
                           ==serviceId).AsNoTracking().firstordefault();

            if(serviceDto!=null)
            {


                    this._Context.catserviceTreatment.Remove(serviceDto);
                    this._Context.SaveChanges();

                   return new catResponse { Success = true, Error = "service 
                              deleted successfully" };
            }

           }catch(exception e)
           {
           } 
      }
```

my collection fixture:

```
      public catContext GetDbContext()
              {
                  var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<catContext>()
                 .UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())

               .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking)

                  .ConfigureWarnings(x => 
                 x.Ignore(InMemoryEventId.TransactionIgnoredWarning))
               //  .ConfigureWarnings(x=>x.Ignore(InMemoryEventId.))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                   .Options;

                var context = new CatDirectoryContext(options);

            var catCategory = new List<catcategory>()
               {
                   new catCategory{Id=100,CategoryName="Youth 
                teereafjkd",UpdatedBy="Test",UpdatedWhen=DateTime.Now},
                 new catCategory{Id=101,CategoryName="Adult 
                fdsafd",UpdatedWhen=DateTime.Now},     
        };

        context.catcategory.AddRange(catCategory);
        context.SaveChanges();


        var catService = new List<catserviceTreatment>()
        {
            new catserviceTreatment{Id=200,Name="House of 
          Hope",Company="",
                Address ="2001 st street",City="alone 
           city",State="UT",ZipCode=8404,Category=null,
                CategoryId =100,Description="this is 
           description",UpdatedBy="test",UpdatedWhen=DateTime.Now},

            new catserviceTreatment{Id=201,Name="Odyssey 
             House",Company="",
                Address ="2001 st",City="bare 
               city",State="UT",ZipCode=84dfd,Category=null,
                CategoryId =101,Description="this is d 
                 description",UpdatedBy="test",UpdatedWhen=DateTime.Now},

        }
        context.catserviceTreatment.AddRange(catService);

        context.SaveChanges();

        return context;

   }
```

Comment: Share your unit test code!

Comment: Your test isn't realistic and should be changed to reflect real application code. The context returned from `GetDbContext` is loaded with entities. In reality you'd get a pristine context to which you can attach anything for the first time. If you change that in your test environment the issue will be solved.

Comment: Hi @GertArnold, Could you please provide simple example of how I have to make my dbcontext as "pristine context " , for every call in unit testing

Comment: Just remove the seeding code and seed the database in test setup methods. Also, make sure you use a new context in each test. Your code doesn't clearly show the context life span, but `_collectionFixture.context` makes me suspect that all tests use the same context.

Comment: yes ,all my tests are using the same context , I am not recreating context in each test . may be this is the reason , it saying entity already tracked

Comment: First of all, you can place `AsNoTracking()` right after the DB set, not after `Where` call:  `...context.cat.AsNoTracking().Where(...)`.

Comment: Second, still don't understand your code. You are searching for some object first and then pass its ID to `DeleteService` method where you again search for the same object and then delete it if found. Why don't you just call `DeleteService(201)` at first place?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you made some query and then navigate through the results of that query and try to delete the found items.
Something like:

```
var catsToDelete = myContext.Cats
        .Where(cat => cat.Id == 204);

foreach (var cat in catsToDelete) {
    myContext.Cats.Remove(cat);
}
```

It will not work this way because each item is still tracked by Entity Framework.

To avoid that tracking you need either to add `ToList()` or `AsNoTracking()` call at the end of the LINQ query:

```
var catsToDelete = myContext.Cats
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Where(cat => cat.Id == 204);

foreach (var cat in catsToDelete) {
    myContext.Cats.Remove(cat);
}
```

Comment: I added AsNotracking and ToList() in my code for query, but still my unit test cases are failing ..

Comment: Could you please post the source of your test here (better in the main question)?

Comment: I'm sorry but your code is a total mess. In the first function, you search for an item with ID 205 and then never use the result and call `DeleteService` with other ID (204).
After that in `DeleteService` you search for all records with the specified ID in `cat` dbset but then try to delete found items from anothe (`BhsdrugAndAlcoholTreatment`) dbset.

Comment: updated my question, sorry I modified code to hide real code, now I updated my question.

Comment: Still, it looks strange. You use `serviceId` as a function parameter but then use `catId` in `Where` call. The result is returned to `serviceDto` but then you use `a` in `Remove` call. 
If actually, the code looks like I think (`serviceId` instead of `catId` and `serviceDto` instead of `a` are used) - then it must work well.

Comment: I updated code just now, sorry again. it's throwing error:" already entity tracked with id:{204}"  . I tried in different ways, but still it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.
During setup I added some test records starting with id 1.
It appeared that the in memory database also starts numbering at 1 when new records are added, causing the "entity already tracked" error.

After I changed my initialization code to use ids as of 101, the problem was solved.